# nav2d toturial 3

Tags: ros, nav2d-exploration, nav2d, nav2d-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and ROS Indigo

i'm trying to launch tutorial 3 for nav2d package. but it seems that there's error in the mapper.

all what i did is
first i launched the toturial3

```
roslaunch nav2d_tutorials tutorial3.launch
```

then  in a separate terminal i call these services as instructed since i don't have a joystick.

```
rosservice call /StartMapping 3
rosservice call /StartExploration 2
```

here is the screen shots of the errors.

[image: image description]

---

here is my rqt_graph

[image: image description]

---

here is my tf view_frames

[image: image description]

[frames.gv](https://ufile.io/07d5f)

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249500/nav2d-toturial-3/) by [alhouty808](https://answers.ros.org/users/28739/alhouty808/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-12-07**:
Looks like the mapper dies right on startup. Can you please send the log file that is mentioned in the error message? And please check your installed boost-version. It should be 1.54.0.1 from Ubuntu 14.04. Have you ever installed another boost version then the one from Ubuntu repositories?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-12-07**:
PS: Do you have installed nav2d as binary package or is it a source build?

**Comment by [alhouty808](https://answers.ros.org/users/28739/alhouty808/) on 2016-12-07**:
as a binary package.  [here is log file](https://ufile.io/3081c)

my boost-version is : 1.54.0.1ubuntu1
i haven't installed another boost version ever.

Thank you for your reply. I really appreciate your time.

**Comment by [alhouty808](https://answers.ros.org/users/28739/alhouty808/) on 2016-12-07**:
I hope you didn't forget me
here is my log file [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5wv39EXLXgZQ29nTWVyU0pfeVU/view?usp=sharing//)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regularly update all your ROS packages to avoid conflicts between packages that have different release versions.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2